# functionality behind the ordered list ( 1, 2,3) when remove some li between the list numbers are auto update how?

Tags: angularjs

When I deleted any item like number 3. order list number are auto update but item number not sync with those num I want to sync item number with li number.

```js
"use strict";

var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

function DemoController($scope){
  $scope.items = [1];
  
  $scope.addItem = function(item){
    $scope.items.push($scope.items.length+1);
    // $scope.newItem = null;
  }
  
  $scope.removeItem = function(index){
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demo">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="DemoController">
    <ol>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{item}}
        <button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)">Remove</button>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <button data-ng-click="addItem(newItem)">Add</button>
    <p>When I deleted any item like number 3. order list number are auto update but item number not sync with those num i want to sync item number with li number</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh8iD00mXdGnPSn4YDqU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

```js
"use strict";

var demo = angular.module("demo", []);

function DemoController($scope){
  $scope.items = [{}];
  
  $scope.addItem = function(item){
    $scope.items.push({});
    // $scope.newItem = null;
  }
  
  $scope.removeItem = function(index){
    $scope.items.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="demo">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-ng-controller="DemoController">
    <ol>
      <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
        {{$index+1}}
        <button data-ng-click="removeItem($index)">Remove</button>
      </li>
    </ol>
    <button data-ng-click="addItem(newItem)">Add</button>
    <p>When I deleted any item like number 3. order list number are auto update but item number not sync with those num i want to sync item number with li number</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Try this